# MVC 3 - How to display a lookup Value in a view Index view instead of an ID field

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a pretty simple need but am unable to figure how it could be done

I have 2 entities

- Employee
- Store

An employee is associated with a store such as (DB)

```
Employee_id, Store_id
1               1  
2               1
```

While in the Index View I need to show the `Store_nam`e instead of the `StoreID`. Which is ideal 'MVC' way of doing it? I am using LINQ to SQL as the data access method.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your model is of type `IEnumerable<Employee>` and you are showing it in a table generated by a foreach loop.

Then you should be able to do this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model){
    Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Store.Store_name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view should be tied to a View Model, which could be an enumerable of models.  But to keep it clean your view model should be custom to the view that is using it, and shouldn't be your Linq to SQL objects.  So, in this case, your View Model would have a property of StoreName.  I haven't tested any of this, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Your Class

```
public class EmployeeModel {
    [HiddentInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int EmployeeID { get;set; }

    [Display("Name = "Store")]
    public string StoreName { get;set; }    
}
```

Your Action

```
public ViewResult EmployeeDetails(int employeeId) {
        var model = new List<EmployeeModel>();

        foreach(var emp in Employees){
            model.Add(new EmployeeModel {
                          EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID,
                          StoreName = emp.Store.StoreName
                      }); 
        }



        return View(model);
    }
```

The view is then pretty straight forward.  There shouldn't be a need to complicate your view with code trying to determine the name of the Store.

```
@model IEnumerable<EmployeeModel>

<h2>Details</h2>


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EmployeeID</th>
            <th>Store Name</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var emp in Model){
         <tr>
             <td>emp.EmployeeID</td>
             <td>emp.StoreName</td>
         </tr>
        }      
    </tbody>

</table>
```

If this is an edit page for the Employee where you can modify the Store, then you could use a select list.